# Keep azure vm updated from one under load balancer

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, load-balancing

I have a simple scenario on azure -> 1 load balancer and three vms under.
The point is every time I need to update my application i need to update it on three vms. 
Is there a way to update it once an let azure know to update it on three vms? or is more a deployment stuff?

Comment: This is something to ask on ServerFault, but... with VM's, you must come up with your own way of maintaining software on your VM's (lots of techniques/ways/tools; what you actually choose to use is a matter of discussion/opinion, which is off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You typically need a strategy for updating, and also for fault handling (in case the server for some reason dies) - these two concepts are known as "Upgrade Domains" and "Fault Domains".

There is a very nice article on how to achieve both here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/

The short answer is that this is very possible, but you need to plan ahead.